# Google fit fetch last record

Tags: android, google-fit

Is it possible to fetch only last record from Google Fit ?
Not timerange, but just one entry from data set.
I need to find time when that record is written.

Let's say I have to sync data from my app with Google Fit. 
I need to know when the last updated record is synced so I could find all values that are newer and not synced yet. 
I can save timestamp in local database, but I think that this is cleaner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setLimit(int limit)` method on the `DataReadRequest.Builder`.

like so:

```
long monthInMillis = 2592000000; // It can be a year or more if you want.. Any way you are limiting the result to 1 DataPoint.
long endTime = new Date().getTime(); // Now
long startTime = endTime - monthInMillis;

DataReadRequest.Builder builder = new DataReadRequest.Builder();
builder.read(dataType);
builder.setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
builder.setLimit(1); // This will get the latest record for the dataType
DataReadRequest readRequest = builder.build(); 

mHistoryClient.readData(readRequest)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {

        for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResponse.getDataSets()) {
            for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                if (dataPoint.getDataType().getName().equals(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE.getName())) {
                    // Location DataPoint
                    long startTime = dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }

                if (dataPoint.getDataType().getName().equals(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT.getName())) {
                    // Activity DataPoint
                    long endTime = dataPoint.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }

                if (dataPoint.getDataType().getName().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA.getName())) {
                    // Steps DataPoint
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

> public DataReadRequest.Builder setLimit (int limit)
>
> Limits results to the latest limit data points. This parameter is ignored for aggregated queries. By default there is no limit.

Doc reference: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/DataReadRequest.Builder.html#setLimit(int)

Comment: Do we need timerange for this (setTimeRange) ?

Comment: You can use a time range if you want.. It will limit results for that specified time range. Just pay attention to this quote from the docs: `This parameter is ignored for aggregated queries` (the setLimit(`parameter`)).

Comment: Okay, but parameters you provided are not sufficient. I get this:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid start time: 0

Comment: ok, so add it :) It's not specified as a must have in the docs.. Just save the last query time stamp and use it next time. I'll add it to the example..

Comment: Okay but time is not mandatory for me. That timestamp can be pretty old, so by adding this param it is possible to miss some data..

Comment: What if last entry happened 5 days ago, and I put 3 days ago as starting point?
I must save that time in local storage. Then getting this value from server is becoming pointless..

Comment: So put 1 years as starting point to play on the safe side, any way you are limiting the query to 1 result (1 DataPoint). See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your time spent on this. Accepted

Comment: You're welcome! I also added a basic parsing example for some DataTypes

Comment: Thanks again for help